# Formatting a DataTable to Datagridview

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagridview

I have a data table that contains the columns Country, Store#, Workweek, and Items Sold

So an example of four rows could be represented as follows:

```
USA    1232    201213    22
USA    1232    201214    24
JAPAN  1231    201213    22
JAPAN  1231    201214    50
```

I want to create a Binded DataGridView that looks like the following,

> ...........**201213**........**201214**
>
> **1230**......22............... 24
>
> **1231**......22................50

So the Store Number is on the Left with each Work Week above, which I want as read only, and the non bolded numbers are editable,  Any help or ideas, would be appreciated, I was looking at maybe using the WPF User Control, but don't know XML so was hoping to stay in WinForms and i could convert the data to a new DataTable then bind, but then I need convert it back to the original. So was just looking for some help in getting started.

Comment: You may get the desired data by executing a SQL SELECT command (_google "SQL PIVOT TABLE"_). Use DataAdapter or DataTable.Load(sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()) to load the SELECT command result in a DataTable. Bind it to the DataGridView and use the ReadOnly properties of Row and or columns.

Comment: Thats perfect actually! Didn't know you could run SQL Select Statements on Datatables.